# How can l retrieve users profile name information such as name and email and profile photo?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

```
private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());

    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        String currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                        DataRef.child("Users").child(currentUserID).child("Name").setValue(name);
                        DataRef.child("Users").child(currentUserID).child("Email").setValue(email);

                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        updateUI();
                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, task.getException().getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    // ...
                }
            });
```

UserInformation Classs:

```
public class UserInformation {

    private String email;
    private String name;

    public UserInformation(){

    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First Assign Firebase User.

```
FirebaseUser firebaseUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
```

Which will hold the data of  user.

There are different methods to retrieve current user data

```
String userEmail = firebaseUser.getEmail();
String uid = firebaseUser.getDisplayName();
String photouri = String.ValueOf(firebaseUser.getPhotoUrl());
```

Comment: Your user login successful or it throws any error ?

Answer (score 0):

In the `task.isSuccessful(){` you need to add:

```java
user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    String uid = user.getUid();
    token = user.getUid();
    email = user.getEmail();
    displayName = user.getDisplayName();
}
```

Comment: it is successful